# filtering and getting a specific value in a json (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Is there a way to get a specific value of my JSON file?

```js
var request = require("request");

var options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: " I entered my database URL here",
  headers: {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "x-apikey": " I entered my api key here"
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  var filter1 = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(filter1.tokenjson);
});
```

and my json file is this:

```json
{
  "center": {
    "tokenjson": "my value here"
  }
}
```

So first I send a get request and receive the JSON file from a database successfully, and then I want to get the value of `tokenjson` and send it in my console. however when I use my code (above), it returns undefined to my console. Thanks if you have read this :)

Comment: `console.log(filter1.center.tokenjson);`

Comment: You have to "chain" to get your `tokenjson` value: `console.log(filter1.center.tokenjson);` You need to specify the whole "path" to the property you want.

Comment: thanks for the response but now it returns 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tokenjson' of undefined

Comment: first console log your response's body to make sure you are receiving the right thing.
`console.log(body)` If that's correct, then `console.log(filter1)' and see what the structure is of the parsed object.

Comment: Vlad S, ok so I tried what you said,
I dropped them in a hastebin link so the comment section won't get messy.
http://www.hastebin.net/womurukeji.vbs

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in [hastebin.net/womurukeji.vbs](http://www.hastebin.net/womurukeji.vbs) you get array in `body`, so try it:

```
console.log(filter1[0].tokenjson);
```